# Is the mistborn adventure game based on another system?

Tags: indie-rpg, mistborn

[The Mistborn Adventure Game](http://www.crafty-games.com/content/buy-mistborn-adventure-game), seems like a very flexible system for using to roleplay certain fictional worlds.
I really like it.

I am wondering if it is based on any other system.
Perhaps FantasyCraft, by the same publisher?

It seems similar in many ways to the [One Roll Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-Roll_Engine).
Similar dice roll mechanic, but swap the d10s for d6s and swap width for Nudges (6es).
Similar initiative/turn order system too.
However other things, such as its particular take on narrative storytelling.
and its notions of distance, and props, and breathers seems different.

Is is based on something?
Have the Authors come out and said: "We were inspired by A,and B from One Roll Engine and by C from Z system?"

I have been messing with a few total conversions of the Mistborn adventure game, to tell other stories (StormLight Archieve, Brent Weeks Lightbrinker series, Jim Butcher's Codex Alera). 
However if it is itself a conversion of something more generic, that might be a better starting point.

Comment: *Most* games have been indirectly based on/inspired by/influenced by other pre-existing game systems. Are you looking for a more direct connection than that? Like, if Mistborn is a direct descendant or sibling of another game system? (Mage: the Awakening and Ars Magica have that kind of tight relationship; as do Unknown Armies and One Roll Engine; if I recall correctly.)

Comment: No, that is about as direct as I expect. Though if there is a more direct one I am interested too.

There is nothing illegal or immoral about taking inspiration. Everything is inspired by something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this review](http://www.rpg.net/reviews/archive/15/15796.phtml) it is an entirely new system:

> As Crafty Games made their splash in the D20 market (Spycraft and Fantasy Craft are both products that make use of the Open Gaming License, or OGL), I was originally expecting the Mistborn Adventure Game to be a supplement to Fantasy Craft or another OGL work. Instead, Crafty Games went in an entirely different direction and created a new set of rules from the ground up.